# Удалить файл из остановленного docker контейнера?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

В контейнере работал sonarqube, попробовал добавить ему плагин через docker cp в /tmp/ сенил ему права и скопировал в /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/ файл sonar-java-plugin-3.2.1.jar, после останвоки контейнера он не стартует
Unable to read plugin manifest from jar : /opt/sonarqube/extensions/plugins/sonar-java-plugin-3.2.1.jar
Подскажите пожалуйста, как удалить файл из остановленного контейнера?
В UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/79325722baf63e572516bfc5208a1a679ef304c9cf2eebeae837d61a71d963d7/diff нашел только тот файл в /tmp/

Comment: скорее всего никак. совсем правильный путь — пересоздать образ без ненужного файла. а если в остановленном контейнере содержится что-то важное невосстановимое, то можно сделать образ прямо из этого контейнера (`man docker-commit`), удалив попутно ненужный файл (см. опцию `--change` в `man docker-commit`).

Comment: спасибо большое!